# How to correctly use SKConstraints

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'd like to build a menu of 'tiles' using `SpriteKit`. For simplicity, the tiles are `SKSpriteNode`s of all the same size, and are housed in a larger 'container' `SKSpriteNode`. The container node is a mask node, so only a subset of the menu tiles are shown at a given time. Dragging up or down on a tile should scroll the list of tiles up or down, respectively.

Right now, when a drag is detected over a tile, I just reposition all tiles up or down--easy. There are two other constraints on the problem, though. The top tile should never scroll below the top of the mask/container node. And, the bottom tile should never scroll above the bottom of the mask/container node. Taken together, this keeps the list of tiles from ever being completely dragged to a place where they are hidden/unreachable.

This problem seemed like it would be elegantly solved with either `SKConstraint`s or `SKPhysicsJoint`s. I've tried a lot of combinations, but nothing seems to give me the desired effect.

For instance, I've used an `SKPhysicsJointFixed` to pin each pair of neighboring tiles together. This has two problems--first, the tiles are 'sluggish' when dragged, so the finger drags more quickly than the tile to the point that it is no longer over the tile, and the drag stops being recognized as on the node. Second, this pin allows the tiles to rotate freely about the anchor point. I added an `SKConstraint` to restrict the z-rotation of every tile, but now the tiles can *barely* be dragged at all.

I tried implementing everything with just `SKConstraint`s, so I wouldn't have to fuss with setting masses correctly, etc., in order to make the physics approach feel more usable. I added a constraint on the x position of every tile so that they could only be dragged vertically. Then, I added another with `SKConstraint.distance(_:toNode:`) on every pair of tiles to keep them separated by the correct vertical distance. The problem with this is, given two tiles, if I add this distance constraint on each, only the *last* tile to be given the constraint is allowed to move. It moves and the other tile follows this tile correctly. That other tile can't be moved at all, though.

Then there comes the problem of keeping at least some part of the set of tiles 'in bounds', so that they never are dragged completely outside of the mask node, and thus not visible/unreachable. A constraint/joint seemed like it might work here--add some constraint/joint to the bottom tile keeping it above the bottom of the mask node, and similarly for the top tile. But now, how do I use a constraint/joint to keep the bottom tile above the bottom of the bottom of the mask node *but let it move below this point*, and vice versa for the top tile?

Am I going about this all wrong? Is using constraints/joints not the correct approach? Obviously, I can hand code all of these restrictions, but it seems like constraints/joints would solve this problem so much more elegantly, while also letting me rely on the physics world for some springiness, flicking, etc. If there's a good way to do what I'm trying to do, would someone please provide a suggestion?

Many thanks!

Comment: I would add invisible nodes (basically lines) above the bottom of your container and below the top and just use collisions to inhibit the dragging

Comment: Right, but the top node *does* need to be able to scroll above the top of the container node, and vice versa for the bottom node. In addition, this still leaves the problem of spacing between the nodes...

Comment: I would use a node to represent the "stack" of tiles and just layout the tile nodes inside it using a loop.  Spacing is just mathematics.  I wouldn't use physics for this.